# Migration tries to create sequence that already exists

Tags: postgresql, .net-core, entity-framework-core, entity-framework-migrations, npgsql

I have a table called checklist in the PostgreSQL database of my .net-core 2.0 app, and have just added  Identity Core following [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?tabs=netcore-cli%2Caspnetcore2x).
Afterwards, I ran:

```
dotnet ef migrations add identity
dotnet ef database update
```

The update resulted in this error:

```
Applying migration '20171018061542_InitialCreate'.
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Command[200102]
      Failed executing DbCommand (2ms) [Parameters=[], CommandType='Text', CommandTimeout='30']
      CREATE SEQUENCE "checklist_id_seq" START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1 NO MINVALUE NO MAXVALUE NO CYCLE;
Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42P07: relation "checklist_id_seq" already exists
```

Would Identity Core also use a table called checklist, or am I making a mistake somewhere?

Edit: The checklist table and sequence checklist_id_seq were not added by Identity.  They were there even before this was a .net-core project (it is EF database first).
I recently added migrations, and lines for checklist_id_seq exist in the initial migration. 
All my tables exist in BOTH 20171018061542_InitialCreate.Designer.cs (the initial migration) and 20171019031817_identity.Designer.cs (the migration I did that I want to create the table(s) used by Identity)

So I guess the question is how to update the database with just the new tables from the "identity" migration?

**Edit2**: Seems like this is an issue with EF Core Migrations. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45737918/ef-core-migrations?rq=1), and these issues:  [4237](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4237) and [2167](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/2167)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Workaround:
Commented out everything in the Up(MigrationBuilder migrationBuilder) method of the initial migration.